# Why is __getitem__ called in Python 3.5 but not in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-internals

I have a subclass of bytes that provides a `__getitem__` dunder method. The `__getitem__` method is always called in Python 3.5, but is called only for non-slice keys in Python 2.7.  (Instead, it appears that parent's `__getitem__` is applied to the instance.)  Why is this and is there a workaround?

## Code

```
class A(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print("in A.__getitem__ with key " + str(key))
        return []

class B(bytes):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print("in B.__getitem__ with key " + str(key))
        return []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    print(sys.version)

    a = A()
    b = B()

    print("[0]")
    a[0]
    b[0]

    print("[0:1]")
    a[0:1]
    b[0:1]

    print("[:1]")
    a[:1]
    b[:1]
```

## Python 3.5 Output

The class-defined `__getitem__` is always called.

```
(venv) snafu$ python ./x.py
3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[0]
in A.__getitem__ with key 0
in B.__getitem__ with key 0
[0:1]
in A.__getitem__ with key slice(0, 1, None)
in B.__getitem__ with key slice(0, 1, None)
[:1]
in A.__getitem__ with key slice(None, 1, None)
in B.__getitem__ with key slice(None, 1, None)
```

## Python 2.7 Output

The class-defined `__getitem__` is called only for non-slice keys.

```
(venv2.7) snafu$ python x.py
2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[0]
in A.__getitem__ with key 0
in B.__getitem__ with key 0
[0:1]
in A.__getitem__ with key slice(0, 1, None)
[:1]
in A.__getitem__ with key slice(None, 1, None)
```

Comment: Doh! It's even weirder: calling `__getitem__` with explicit slices (e.g., `b[slice(0,1,None)]`) *works* on both Python 2.7 and 3.5. It appears that in Python 2.7, writing `b[s:e]` is *not* the same thing as `b[slice(s,e)]` when b is a subclass of a built-in type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2 has [`__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__), which takes priority over `__getitem__` for stepless slicing if present. That's gone in Python 3.